# Get first item from list created by sql

Tags: php, sql-server

I have created a list

php code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM itinerary WHERE id= ".$id;
$connect = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array) {
    echo "<li>{$day}</li>";
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
</ul>
```

with PHP and MySQL.

The numbers of `<li>` tags are dynamic and change on every page.

How can I get the first `<li>` and display it in a different position in the page?

e.g. I have an itinerary list and I want to display the departure place from first `<li>` but I want the whole list as well.

**UPDATE** `<p class="itin">Departure: <?php echo $day;?></p>` I want to display that here, but like this I get just the last item.

Comment: Show us your PHP code which generated that list.  This is probably a presentation layer thing rather a SQL problem.

Comment: So it should be somewhere else and not inside the ul?

Comment: @TobiasF. yes thats right

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen UPDATED

Comment: OK but where is the HTML for the other position?  We need this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean variable to identify its the first value being returned.
Save that value in another variable and skip the '`echo <li>...`' command.
Now you can use that variable anywhere afterwards in the document.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM itinerary WHERE id= ".$id;
$connect = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);
$first = true;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array) {
  if($first){
     $this_is_first_day = $day;
     $first = !$first;
  } else {
      echo "<li>{$day}</li>";
  }
}

//Lot of other things going here
?>
<p class="itin">Departure: <?php echo $this_is_first_day;?></p>
```

output:

```
<ul>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
</ul>

<p class="itin">Departure: a</p>
```

Comment: Can I put a inside <li> and outside in <b> as well>

Comment: Didn't understand your question

Comment: I need a(first day) to be inside <li> and siplay it as well again in <p> e.g <li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li>     and also <p class="itin">Departure: a</p>

Answer (score 0):

using css you have target firs li in ul.

```
ul li:first-child { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```